# Hive create table statement for Fluentd Apache log data

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, fluentd

I'm using Fluentd to capture and consolidate Apache log data in HDFS. I configured the agent to write the data to HDFS, i.e. the `/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf` file contains:

```
<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/httpd/access_log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/httpd-access.log.pos
  tag apache.access
  format apache2
</source>

<match apache.access>
  type webhdfs
  host fqdn.of.name.node
  port 50070
  path /data/access_logs/access.log.%Y%m%d_%H.${hostname}.log
  flush_interval 10s
</match>
```

I enabled HDFS appends per the [Fluentd documentation](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_webhdfs). The data streams across perfectly. It's been streaming millions of transactions without a glitch for the past couple of weeks.

The data is stored in files that contain lines like this:

```
2015-01-10T17:00:00Z    apache.access   {"host":"155.96.21.4","user":null,"method":"GET","path":"/somepage/index.html","code":200,"size":8192,"referer":null,"agent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"}
```

Each row contains three tab separated elements:

1. timestamp
2. an identifying tag
3. JSON containing key/value pairs for the columns in the Apache log

I'm trying to create a Hive table and aren't sure how to handle the fact that it's a mixture of tab separated strings and JSON on each row. I know that Hive has a JSON deserializer, but I don't think that'll work because the records aren't pure JSON.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to write a create table statement for this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following parameter to your out_wedhdfs config:

```
output_data_type json
```

This should be documented. I will update the docs soon.